# how can you count number of digits used in numbers from -2^127 to (2^(127) - 1)

Tags: permutations, combinations

There are numbers from -2^127 to (2^127)-1.
I want to count the number of digits used in all the numbers.

For example
If I have numbers from -100 to 100 
then number of digits used is $2*(1*9 + 2*90 + 3*1) + 1$ (including 0 only once)
9 numbers having 1 digit.
90 numbers having 2 digits.
1 number having 3 digits.
but same for all -100 to 0 numbers therefore double the answer
and we forgot the 0 so $+ 1$.

Comment: It goes just the same way, just a lot longer. And the last *group* of powers of ten is incomplete. You can convert this into a weird iincomplete Arithmetic-Geometric Progression, i think. But that wouldn't go much nicer.

Comment: @chubakueno Any shorter method ?

Comment: Wouldn't there be 90 two digit numbers? You would have a truncated $\sum_{n=0}^{}9(n+1)10^n$ Actually that we

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[There are 90 two-digit positive integers, not 89.]

Note that $38<\log_{10}(2^{127}-1)<39$, so $2^{127}$ has 39 digits. Then the number of digits in numbers from $1$ to $2^{127}-1$ is $$d=1\cdot9+2\cdot90+3\cdot900+\cdots+38\cdot9\cdot{10}^{37}+39\cdot(2^{127}-10^{38}),$$
and the number of digits used in the numbers from $-2^{127}$ to $2^{127}-1$ is therefore $2d+2=13048790087694377852849387467616738024564$.

If each digit weighs one microgram, this is several times the mass of the sun.

Comment: Count them: 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99. There are 90. It’s easy to see there must be an even number, because they go even, odd, even, odd, ... even, odd.

Comment: Yup. We could factor the $9$ and do this as an artithmetic-geometric series sum and correct the last truncated term, but I don't know if that would be worthy.

Comment: @MukulKumar you are counting [10-99] **inclusive** . This is a common confusion , is called the [fencepost problem](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) :)

Comment: Oh, yes Now I got it So there are actually 101 numbers! not 100. @chubakueno The confusion was never there in my mind (fencepost problem), but I thought that there are 100 numbers from 0 - 100 but there are 101 numbers!

Comment: @MukulKumar *That* is the fencepost problem! It happens often, even more when programming languages with  0-indexed arrays, trust me :)

Comment: @chubakueno Curse my brain for using shortcuts! (saw on TV that brain uses shortcuts to provide answers which are wrong some-tines)